# What is the winning strategy for this deterministic game?

Tags: game-theory, axiom-of-choice, infinite-games

I was trying to solve one of the questions in Herrlich's book "The Axiom of Choice" and got stuck on the second part of this problem. The game in question as described by Herrlich is:

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $A$ a subset of $X^\mathbb{N}$. The game $G(X,A)$ is played as follows:

Two players choose alternate elements $x_0,x_1,x_2, \dots$ in $X$, such that each player knows, (besides $X$ and $A$), whenever it is his term, the tuple of previously chosen elements. The first player (who chooses $x_0,x_2,x_4,\dots$) wins if the resulting sequence $(x_n)$ belongs to $A$. Otherwise the second player (who chooses $x_1,x_3,x_4,\dots$) wins. The game is determined if one of the players has a winning strategy.

Consider $A=[{(x_n) \in 2^{\mathbb{N}} : \forall_n x_{2n+1}=x_{2n}}]$ and the constant sequence $(0)$.

1)The second player has a winning strategy for $G(2,A)$.

2)The first player has a winning strategy for $G(2,A \cup \left\{ (0) \right\})$.

My solution for (1) is as follows:

Player 2 can easily win this game by ensuring for whatever $x_0$ player 1 first plays, they play $x_1 \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, ensuring $x_1 \neq x_0$, resulting in the sequence necessarily not being in $A$.

However I don't see how the first player can have a winning strategy for part (2) such that $(x_n) \in A$. Am I miss understanding what the constant sequence $(0)$ means?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The choices of the players and the rules for winning seem to be missing. Perhaps $2^{\mathbb{N}}=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and you mean $x_{2n+1}=x_{2n}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What does $\forall x_{2n+1}=x_{2n}$ mean?

Comment: Apologies everyone! I'm new to posting and wasn't sure what definitions of infinite games were considered standard. I have outlined the game in question and provided my solution to part (1). I hope this is clear.

Comment: Are you sure you got the definition of $A$ correct? The constant sequence is already in $A$ so $A\cup\{(0)\}=A$. Or did you mean $A-\{(0)\}$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the definition of $A$ is correct as written in the book and formatted exactly the same. This has currently stumped both myself and my dissertation supervisor. If anyone happens to have the book, it is page 157, exercises to section 7.2, E2.

Comment: I imagine that the intention is that for question 1, the second player can do a copying strategy to force a sequence that lies in $A$, and thereby win (which is the opposite of the winning condition described in the question), and that for question 2 the first player can win by always choosing 0 so that the second player either abandons his strategy and loses, or follows his strategy and still loses because the result is the constant zero sequence. So the winning condition is described wrongly: Player two should win when the resulting sequence is in $A$ or $A-\{(0)\}$ respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a typo; in particular, $(0)$ is already in $A$ as defined! Unfortunately, given that the exercise is so short, it's hard to figure out what the author meant.

Here's one possible interpretation. Clearly the author intends $(0)$ to be pivotal in some way; basically, we can assume that "both players $1$ and $2$ wait for the other to play $1$" is a plausible outcome of playing the original game $G(2,A)$ (of course player $2$ should ultimately win here, but player $1$ shouldn't have an incentive to play a $1$ early). This suggests that in the original game, player $1$ should win iff the least $k$ such that $x_k=1$ exists and is odd. **Yes, this is quite far from what's written**, but I've seen (and made!) mistakes like this before, where the author/speaker/Noah in question thinks that some snappy symbolic expression successfully captures a rather complicated condition when it *really* doesn't.

To be honest, though, that's just a guess; the typo here is pretty fatal, and I'd just pass over this exercise entirely.

Comment: This has been really helpful and certainly what I needed in regards to my problem! Than you, Noah.